# Will the coroutines bypass the flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using coroutines for a network call and was wondering if there's any better way for a network call with suspend.

The requirement is:

1. Call the network API
2. halt the execution till the response received
3. act upon API response

Activity:

```
private fun prepareUnlockUrl(url: String) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val result = async { mViewModel.requestAccess(url) }

            when (result.await()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "do something with 'result'")
            }
        }
    }
```

and the ViewModel consists:

```
suspend fun requestAccess(url: String): Response {
      return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            // Do network call and get response
            continuation.resume(response)
      }
}
```

Comment: Depends on which network API you are using. It might have built in support for coroutines.

Comment: It's an internal API using retrofit + repository pattern

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that are wrong in `prepareUnlockUrl`:

1. You should not create a coroutine scope on the fly like this. A scope should be tied to some sort of lifecycle and be cancelled appropriately.

   - if you just need to run something in a particular coroutine context, you can use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` instead. Note that this is a suspending function, so you're just changing the context, not creating a coroutine here.
   - if you really want to create a coroutine (if you cannot make your function `suspend`), you should already have a ready-to-use coroutine scope available in activities, such as `lifecycleScope` (check out [this doc about coroutines in Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines))
2. calling `async` and then `await()` right away is never useful.

   - If you don't change the coroutine context via the `async` call (which is your case here), you could simply call the suspend function directly without wrapping in `async` and it will have the same effect
   - If you did use a custom coroutine context in the `async` call (which you don't here), you could simply use `withContext(someContext) { suspendCall }` instead `async(someContext) { suspendCall() }.await()`

So in the end I think you should either write:

```kotlin
private suspend fun prepareUnlockUrl(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    mViewModel.requestAccess(url)
    Log.i(TAG, "do something with 'result'")
}
```

Or if you can't make your function `suspend` for some reason, launch a coroutine in the existing `lifecycleScope`:

```kotlin
private fun prepareUnlockUrl(url: String) = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    mViewModel.requestAccess(url)
    Log.i(TAG, "do something with 'result'")
}
```

Now regarding `requestAccess`, I can't really tell unless you should how exactly the network call is made, but fortunately this is independent from the other problems.

Comment: Thanks, the reason for opting for coroutines was to wait for the result from `requestAccess()`. I prefer the second form mentioned above if it will serve the purpose.

Comment: @Faisal using suspend functions is already making use of coroutines, the difference is at which level we start the coroutine to do the work. Usually the idea is to keep suspend functions as much as possible and then start the coroutines in the top level components that have a lifecycle and therefore can define proper coroutine scopes (like components that have `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope`).

Comment: Is there any limitation in accessing shared preference from `suspend` method or `suspendCoroutine` block?

Comment: @Faisal No limitation to my knowledge, but I haven't done Android dev in a while :D It should be ok, because you can always call any function from suspend functions (the converse is not true). That is, unless there is special threading constraints, in which case you should make sure to use the right dispatcher using `withContext` (for instance, don't use `commit()` on your main thread, use `apply()` instead)